# Shell : while read line nested

Tags: shell, text-processing, io-redirection, read

I've two documents: doc1.lst and doc 2.lst
I want to take the content of each line and put it as parameters for my SQL query.

I tried something like this, please correct me

```
    file=doc1.lst
    while read line
    do
       p1=$line;

    file=doc2.lst
    while read line
    do
       p2=$line;

        sqlplus64 $User/$Pass@$ORACLE_SID << EOF2
        @update.sql p1 p2

    done < echo "Ok"
    done < echo "Ok"
    EOF2
```

The thing is that I want to take the value of each line and put it as a parameter (p1 and p2) to be able to update my table as seen in the sqlplus query.

For a better understanding my file doc1.lst looks like :

```
    AAA
    ABC
    EDF
```

And my file doc2.lst :

```
    30
    10
    30
```

I want to take those values to update my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it (the `<<EOF2` stuff at the end isn't crystal-clear), the end result you're after is to feed the following into `sqlplus64`:

```
@update.sql AAA 30
@update.sql ABC 10
@update.sql EDF 30
```

To produce this, instead of looping over the contents of both files, you can combine them. Using `paste` on both files (`paste doc1.lst doc2.lst`) gives

```
AAA     30
ABC     10
EDF     30
```

(`paste` joins with tabs by default). Changing the delimiter with `paste -d ' ' doc1.lst doc2.lst` gives

```
AAA 30
ABC 10
EDF 30
```

Then we need to add `@update.sql` as a prefix; this can be done with `sed`, replacing the start of each line (`^`) with the prefix:

```
paste -d ' ' doc1.lst doc2.lst | sed 's/^/@update.sql /'
```

produces the desired result.

This can then be fed in one shot into `sqlplus64`:

```
paste -d ' ' doc1.lst doc2.lst | sed 's/^/@update.sql /' | sqlplus64 $User/$Pass@$ORACLE_SID
```

If you need `exit` at the end of the script fed into `sqlplus64`:

```
(paste -d ' ' doc1.lst doc2.lst | sed 's/^/@update.sql /'; echo exit) | sqlplus64 $User/$Pass@$ORACLE_SID
```

If you really want to run things line by line, you can `while read` each line of the result and feed that to `sqlplus64` instead.