# An error of variable type?

Tags: shell, variable, parameter, sql

I've an error that I don't understand, it seems that that the problem is that my parameters into the shell are not of the same type as what they are in my SQL Database.

For a better understanding: I've a file doc.lst where i've three important things on each line seperated by spaces and i want to use this things as parameter for an UPDATE in my database. Every line will be readen, every part will be used as a parameter and will update my database.

I've a SQL query that is :

```
    UPDATE PE P
    SET P.DATED='&1', P.DATEF='&1', P.CODA='&3', P.CODB='&2'
    WHERE P.G_BAT=1;
    COMMIT;
```

And a shell that is :

```
    IFS=$'\n'
    for i in $(cat $LST_HOME/doc.lst)
    do 
    sqlplus64 $User/$Pass@$ORACLE_SID << EOF
    P1=$(echo $i | awk '{print $1}')
    P2=$(echo $i | awk '{print $2}')
    P3=$(echo $i | awk '{print $3}')
    @$SQL_HOME/update_p.sql $P1 $P2 $P3
    commit;
    exit
    /data/jdk1.6.0_XX/bin/java -cp fr.bla.bla.bla 
    EOF
```

I've got this error :

```
    SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command at the beggining of "P1=12/03/2..." - end of the line is ignored.
    SQL> SP2-0042: unknown command "P2=0" - end of the line is ignored..
    SQL> SP2-0042: unknown command "P3=FSL" - end of the line is ignored..
```

I don't really understand where and how i've to make modifications.

Comment: You need to do `set -f` first before doing all of  that `$IFS` splitting. Anyone of those vars could expand to shell globs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in [Shell : while read line nested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189541/shell-while-read-line-nested), you can just do something like

```
(sed "s|^|@${SQL_HOME}/update_p.sql |" ${LST_HOME}/doc.lst; echo exit) | sqlplus64 ${UserCoribudg}/${PassCoribudg}@${ORACLE_SID}
```

If you want to run a command after every SQL update, you could loop, although there are a number of caveats (globbing etc.). If the values in your `doc.lst` are safe, you can do

```
while read line; do
    (echo @${SQL_HOME}/update_p.sql ${line}; echo exit) | sqlplus64 ${UserCoribudg}/${PassCoribudg}@${ORACLE_SID}
    /data/java_1.6_XX/bin/java -cp fr.bla.bla.bla
done < ${LST_HOME}/doc.lst
```

without needing to parse each line.

A safer option is to turn the whole file into a shell script:

```
sed "s|^|(echo @${SQL_HOME}/update_p.sql |" ${LST_HOME}/doc.lst | sed "s/$/; echo exit | sqlplus64/" | sed "s|$| ${UserCoribudg}/${PassCoribudg}@${ORACLE_SID}; /data/java_1.6_XX/bin/java -cp fr.bla.bla.bla|" > doc.script
sh doc.script
```

Comment: The solution with the while gives me "SQL> SP2-0734: command not found  at the beggining of "/data/to..." (this is my $SQL_HOME) - the end of the line is ignored". But it starts my .xml generation.

Comment: Oops, sorry, the `@` was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4):

setting of shell variable should be made before sqlplus call

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat $LST_HOME/doc.lst)
do 
P1=$(echo $i | awk '{print $1}')
P2=$(echo $i | awk '{print $2}')
P3=$(echo $i | awk '{print $3}')

sqlplus64 $UserCoribudg/$PassCoribudg@$ORACLE_SID << EOF
@$SQL_HOME/update_p.sql $P1 $P2 $P3
commit;
exit
EOF

/data/java_1.6_XX/bin/java -cp fr.bla.bla.bla

done
```

- `P1=whatever` is not a valid sql code.
- I assume java part make use of updated values.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but the problem is that at the end of every line i've to update my table with the datas of the line. I've a java command that creates a .xml that's why I wanted to use a while. At the moment it only update in the data base the last line.

Comment: That's because your `WHERE` condition is probably wrong; you're applying all the updates to the same lines, so only the last update is kept.

Comment: As you probably have understood, I don't master awk or sed command. So I don't really know how to do because since those command are searching something this is a kind of loop. Can I use wc -l < doc.lst and use the result as a variable (called j), set i to 0 and to do something like while i < j *Archemar's answer* *my command to generate xml* i++ ? It sound impossible to me because even if something like this would work with Archemar's solution it will make all the updates and then use the command to generate. So it'll be every time the last line that is uploaded.

Comment: Edit your question to show where xml file is generated, however, the WHERE condition seems strange, your basically doing set month=january where year=2015 ; set month=february where year=2015 ;  ... set month=december where year=2015 ; the first 11 statement are useless ...

Comment: I've edited my question